# Unknown protocol error while using request api ( node.js )

Tags: node.js

Here is my code. I am running 0.10.24 version. Can someone look into this? An error, "Error: 6304:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:766:" is displayed.

```
var url = require('url'),
    request = require('request'),
    loginLink = "https://foo";

var params = {
    maxRedirects: 10,
    followRedirect: true,
    followAllRedirects: true,
    timeout: 10000,
    url: url.parse(loginLink),
    method: "POST",
    jar: true,
    strictSSL: false,
    form: {
        'userid': 'userid',
        'pwd': 'pass',
        'timezoneOffset': -330  
    },
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1753.0 Safari/537.36',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Origin': 'https://foo'
    }
}

request(params,function(error,response,body){
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        console.log(body);
    }else{
        console.log(response);
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change SSL version (?)

```
options = {
    ....
    strictSSL: false,
    secureProtocol: 'SSLv3_client_method',
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks @damphat. It worked! Btw, how did you zero in on that? There is no mention of such option on the github page of the package. Even the nodejs.org api site does not say anything.

Comment: @identifyMe you can read document at http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback